# Python Downloading an S3 file without knowing key name

Tags: python, amazon-athena

I am writing a Python script that runs a query through Athena, outputs it to S3 and downloads it into my computer. I am able to run my query through Athena and output the result into S3. So my next step that I can’t seem to figure out is how to download it to my computer without knowing the key name?

Is there a way to lookup the object key within my python script after outputting it to Athena?

What I have completed:

```
# Output location and DB
s3_output = ‘s3_output_here’
database = ‘database_here’

# Function to run Athena query
def run_query(query, database, s3_output):
    while True:
        try:
            response = client.start_query_execution(
                QueryString=query,
                QueryExecutionContext={
                    'Database': database
                    },
                ResultConfiguration={
                    'OutputLocation': s3_output,
                    }
                )
            return response
            break
        except client.exceptions.TooManyRequestsException as e:
            print('Too many requests, trying again after sleep')
            time.sleep(100)

# Our SQL Query    
query = """
SELECT *
FROM test
”””

print("Running query to Athena...")
res = run_query(query, database, s3_output)
```

I understand how to download a file with this code:

```
try:
    s3.Bucket(BUCKET_NAME).download_file(KEY, ‘KEY_HERE’)
except botocore.exceptions.ClientError as e:
    if e.response['Error']['Code'] == "404":
        print("The object does not exist.")
    else:
        raise
```

So how can I read the key name after running my first completed code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the key using the get_key command provided by the boto library.  This is how I download things from s3:

```
    with open("path/aws-credentials.json") as f:
        data= json.load(f)
        conn = boto.connect_s3(data["accessKeyId"], data["secretAccessKey"])
    bucket = conn.get_bucket('your_bucket')
    file_path = bucket.get_key('path/to/s3/file')
    file_path.get_contents_to_filename('path/on/local/computer/filename')
```

You can hardcode your credentials into the code if you are just testing something out, but if you are planning on putting this into production, it's best to store your credentials externally in something like a json file.

Comment: What if I do not know what the file name will be? For that last line

Comment: Hmm, well that sort of depends on how the file name will be determined.  For instance, if you have a function that figures out which file to get, simply make sure that the filename is present in the return statement and include something like:

          `filename = file_getter_function(args)
          file_path.get_contents_to_filename('path/on/local/computer/%s' %filename)`

It's hard to say without knowing how the file is being determined, but somewhere someone has to enter a filename or a program has to pick one or something, and you can use that information for the database call.

Comment: In your case,  I suppose it would be whatever is determining your "s3_output", so it would be `('path/on/local/computer/%s' %s3_output)`.

Comment: Oh wait sorry! I understand now I misinterpreted the code. One last thing, path/aws-credentials.json...would the path be the link to my s3_output?

Comment: No, that would just be a json file you would create that would contain your aws credentials.  If you are just using this for yourself or testing something out, you can just drop those first two lines and start with `conn = boto.connect_s3("accessKeyId", "secretAccessKey")`, with your access key and secret key in those fields.  You don't want to do this in production code because then your passwords are just sitting out in the open, hence the json file.

Comment: The file_path is the path to whatever you are getting off of s3.  The last line is where you want to save it on your computer and what you want to call it.  The aws-credentials.json is a json file that would contain your aws-credentials.  It's not necessary to make the code work but it keeps your passwords secure.

Comment: I am getting an attribute error on the last line AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_contents_to_filename' ...... file_path.get_contents_to_filename('Users/bianca/documents/python/athena.csv')

Comment: print file_path and see what it gives you...  You may have the wrong path in s3.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184637/discussion-between-bey-and-jeremiah).